# How can I put a canvas attachment into an embed?

Tags: discord.js, canvasjs

My current code wont work, dont really know how to attach the file

```
            const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer());

            let embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Hello`)
                .setDescription(Welcome!`)
                .setImage(attachment)
                .setColor(embedColor)

            message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: Voting to close since the question is missing details and does not state what the problem is.

Comment: I do not know how to attach a canvas file (the canvas picture) into an embed, im sorry if what I gave was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the porting guide to v13, as you have the newer syntax for embeds listed, this implies this is your version...

```
channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: ['./image1.png', './image2.jpg'] });
```

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc